# flask-paginate how to style the page numbers?

Tags: html, css, pagination

I don't want to install bootstrap and I managed to find a way around it to style it in my own way. My pagination is working fine as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whSYX.png). It's just, I can't style the a:active link to show a different background color. Here's my css, .page is the div containing the {{ pagination.links }}:

```
.content .big-box .page {
list-style-type: none;
display: flex;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
right: 0px;
bottom: 15px;
border: none;
} 

.content .big-box .page li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.content .big-box .page li:active {
background-color: black;
}

.content .big-box .page li a {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
color: white;
padding: 5px;
background-color: grey;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.content .big-box .page a:hover {
background-color: #696969;
}

.content .big-box .page a:active {
background-color: black;
}
```

I went through the [documentation](https://flask-paginate.readthedocs.io/en/master/), but I still didn't succeed. I've done a lot of testing today and finally came to the solution that these number and arrow components are a and li.
I tried to style the li:active, a:active, ul:active, p:active, span:active, button:active, but nothing seems to work. Everything else works but :active, :hover works as expected and all the other styling as well. Someone enlighten me, please!

EDIT: Here is the code I want to style. I use .page .pagination ul .active a:active {background-color: black;}, but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="pagination">
    <ul>
      <li class="previous disabled unavailable"><a> &laquo; </a></li>
      <li class="active"><a>1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/forum/obavijesti/silazno/?page=2">2</a></li>
      <li class="next"><a href="/forum/obavijesti/silazno/?page=2">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your browser, open the developer tools and inspect the element you want to style. There you see exactly what kind of html element this is and what other styles are applied to it.

For Chrome the documentation can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Once you know what you want to style, you have to apply the correct style with the correct weight.

CSS stands for **Cascading Style Sheets**, that finally means, the style which you finally see is "calculated" from inline styles, IDs, classes and more.

You can learn more about CSS here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS

**Update**

I copy pasted your code on my local machine, and

```
<style>
    .page .pagination ul .active a:active {background-color: black;}
</style>
```

works like a charm for me.

Are you exactly sure what that means?

This means, only style the already active link and only when you click on it.

In your example HTML code this means only work when click on the link marked with `1` - which makes no sense to me, as you cannot click it :-)

Maybe you want to remove the `.active` specifier?

Comment: Okay, so the div in question is   `<div class="page"><div class="pagination"><ul><li class="previous disabled unavailable"><a> &laquo; </a></li><li class="active"><a>1</a></li><li><a href="/forum/obavijesti/silazno/?page=2">2</a></li><li class="next"><a href="/forum/obavijesti/silazno/?page=2">&raquo;</a></li></ul></div></div>` and I style it like this: `.page .pagination ul .active a:active {background-color: black;}` but it doesn't work

Comment: How do I paste code in the comment? Sorry, I'm new around here. EDIT: figured it out

Comment: You cannot put a lot of code in the comments. Maybe you want to update your question with it.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question. Thank you for replying on such a short notice.

Comment: HAHAHAAHAHAHAHA, thank you for clarifying this for me. I'm new to all this, but I have big dreams. You sir are a legend

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. I'd appreciate if you upvote or accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I did, but we newbs with less than 15 reputation are useless